# New to javascript and if-else functions. (No error message in the console log)

Tags: javascript, html, function, variables, if-statement

So I am doing a small project and cannot seem to get this function to work. any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="loginForm">
        <label>Password:</label> 
        <input type="password" id="passwordField">
        <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="checkPassword()">
        <p><output id="outputField"></output></p>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

here is the script.

```
var passwordField = "apple"
var checkPassword = function (checkPassword, passwordField) {
if (passwordField == "apple") {
    {document.loginForm.outputField.value = "You did it!";}
}
else {
    {document.loginForm.outputField.value = "Fail.";}
}
};
```

Comment: You're very confused. You don't want a `checkPassword` parameter to your function--that's its name. Also, you're calling `checkPassword` on the click, but not passing it any parameter. Why would you expect it to work? By the way, `if-else` is not a function, it's a statement.

Comment: I am in fact very confused, sorry I'm very new to coding. This clears a lot up.

Answer (score 1):

**My recommendation**

```
var passwordField = 'apple';

function checkPassword(input) {
    return (input == 'apple') ? 'You did it!' : 'Fail';
};
```

call it like so

```
<script>
    document.write(checkPassword(passwordField));
</script>
```

Comment: Why would either of those things make a difference? And what exactly is wrong with `var checkPassword`?

Answer (score 0):

First, in JavaScript:

Remove `checkPassword` parameter from method `checkpassword`. Why do you need it?
You don't need inner brackets, it makes no sense.

```
var passwordField = "apple";
var checkPassword = function (passwordField) {
    if (passwordField == "apple") {
        document.loginForm.outputField.value = "You did it!";
    }
    else {
        document.loginForm.outputField.value = "Fail.";
    }
};
```

And in HTML:

You have to pass password to your function, otherwise it will be `undefined` and it will never pass.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="loginForm">
        <label>Password:</label> 
        <input type="password" id="passwordField">
        <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="checkPassword(document.getElementById('passwordField').value)">
        <p><output id="outputField"></output></p>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```